# Serialize a object to the smallest UTF8 compatible size

Tags: c#, serialization, utf-8

I've got an quite simple class that contains some primitive types and some collections with mostly enums. Now I need to serialize this object to the smallest possible size that is UTF8 compatible.

This is the class I need to serialize

```
public class Context
{
    public Hashtable UserModuleRoles { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> CustomSettings { get; set; }
    public int Uid { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ActiveId { get; set; }
    public byte Default { get; set; }
    public SetEnum Ident { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public sbyte State { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

.

This is how I serialize the object

```
public string Serialize(object serializeObject)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();

    b.Serialize(stream, serializeObject);

    byte[] data = stream.ToArray();

    stream.Dispose();
    stream = new MemoryStream();

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddEntry("data", data);
        zip.Save(stream);
    }

    data = stream.ToArray();
    stream.Dispose();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}
```

In my first attempt I serialize the object, zip that content (about 1/3 smaller) and convert it to a base64 string. But base64 has a quite big overhead of 1/3 and I know there is base128 but I don't know how to start and my search for base128 encoding was unsuccessful.

- **Or is there any other way to do this?**
- *And if not how is the best way to

  this as base128?*

Edit:

I tested the ObjectStateFormatter Class with the whole "Context" object which results in 8byte more and slower serialization/deserialization. Maybe I had to use it just on the properties instead of the whole class?

Comment: What do you mean, "UTF-8 compatible"?

Comment: The result will be stored in a cookie and as far as I know UTF-8 is the standard here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, base128 is not that hard, if you know how base64 is done. The dutch wikipedia describes the process well (translated it for you):

1. Convert the data to binary.
2. Keep taking chunks of 7 bits (2^7 = 128)
3. Convert those 7 bits to an integer.
4. Look up that integer in a translation table that you defined and append the character found to the base128 string.

That translation table contains 128 compatible UTF8 characters, for example:

```
0: a
1: b
..
25: z
26: 0
```

The only requirement is that translation table is the same at both sender and reciever.

Comment: Thanks! That will help me in that case. But there is still the question if it is the best solution or if there is a better one.

Comment: We cannot tell you if it is the "best solution" you have not given us enough to work with.

Comment: OK, I've posted the code of the serialize method and the class to serialize. I don't know what else you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `objectstateformatter` instead of the `BinaryFormatter`, might give you a smaller size. It all depends on the data your serializing.

Comment: OK, I will give it a try tomorrow and compare the size. The biggest part will be the hashtable which contains only enums. Or maybe not the biggest but the part with the most values.

Comment: OK, finally I tested it. In my simple test it was about 8 byte larger then the plain byte Stream and much slower. I dunno why because all datatypes within the object are fully compatible with the objectstateformatter class, according to the msdn. Maybe I will get better results if I serialize just the values and nothing from the object. But then I will end up in more then ten single streams and... no, that doesn't sound good to me. Or did I miss something in my test?